# Pull multiple records from different groups in Oracle based off value in different column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

It might sound a little convoluted, so I'll try to keep it brief. Essentially I need to run a query that groups the results based on `COL1`, and from there it looks at the maximum value in `COL2`. Once it determines what is the highest value in `COL2`, it should then look at the value in `COL3`, and then pull every record in the group that has the same value. There are other columns in the table that I need values from, but they aren't used in the query logic.

```
SOME_TABLE

  COL1    COL2     COL3
1 12345   100      A
2 12345   (null)   A
3 12345   50       B
4 12346   0        A
5 12346   (null)   A
6 12346   100      B
7 12346   20       B
```

So in this example for rows with `COL1` value of `12345`I would want rows `1` and `2` (it just needs a single instance of the highest value, it doesn't matter what the rest of the rows' values are). For `COL1` with the value of `12346` I need rows with `B` in `COL3`.

Here's sample output in a little bit more of a readable format:

```
  COL1    COL2     COL3
1 12345   100      A
2 12345   (null)   A
6 12346   100      B
7 12346   20       B
```

I have tried numerous different queries and permutations of the queries, but with no luck. I'm not sure how constructive it would be to post a bunch of queries that don't work. The biggest two approaches I've tried include a regular `GROUP BY` statement, and then also `PARTITION BY` on `COL1`.

I should also note that I tried implementing this on the `C#` side of the application, and also using looping in the `SQL` script but results were either mixed or the performance was incredibly poor.

I haven't found anything useful across SO or in Oracle's "documentation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the rows where the col3 values matches the max for `col1`.  A correlated subquery seems like the most natural way to express this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col3 = (select max(t2.col3) keep (dense_rank first order by col2 desc)
                from t t2
                where t2.col1 = t.col1
               );
```

The long `keep` expression is just saying "keep the first value of `col3` for the biggest value of `col2`.

Comment: This did the trick. The performance is pretty phenomenal too.

Comment: @Dortimer . . . `keep` always surprises me performance-wise.  The syntax is so long but the performance is fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT t.*, MAX(col2) OVER(PARTITION BY col1) m FROM t)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (COL1,COL3) IN (SELECT col1, col3 FROM cte WHERE col2 = m);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a8eb1796b91ef4695dac0891dcb77278)**

Output:

```
+-----+--------+-------+------+
| ID  | COL1   | COL2  | COL3 |
+-----+--------+-------+------+
|  2  | 12345  |       | A    |
|  1  | 12345  |  100  | A    |
|  7  | 12346  |   20  | B    |
|  6  | 12346  |  100  | B    |
+-----+--------+-------+------+
```

Comment: It will fail for data `3 12345   100       B` . Refine your WHERE.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but should I replace `t` with anything? I tried using `FROM some_table t` for the `WITH` portion, but I'm not having any luck with running the query.

Comment: @Dortimer `t` is your table name and you have so change every occurence of t with `some_table`. You have 3 of them `t.*`, `FROM t` in cte and `FROM t` in main query.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but @Serg was correct in their comment. This query didn't generate the desired results.

Comment: @Dortimer How you could want to select value when you have obvious tie? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6cc810234381458992f16347d8a02d35ult

Comment: @LukaszSzozda with a more complex set of data, it pulled multiple different values from Col3, instead of just one unique value shared through the resulting rows.

Comment: @Dortimer How would you like to handle ties? If you have a tie in max value  you have to prefer one value over another. You should define a logic that explicitly states which value should be taken. Or you simply want to use `ORDER BY ..` and grab the first one and let the query optimizer to do it. But doing it that way you will get undeterministic results across multiple runs.

Answer (score 0):

Sample expected output might help.  Try this:

```
    select col1, col3, max(col3)
    from table
    group by col1, col3
```

Comment: Updated the question with the expected output in a more clear format.